# Drop Down for Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium

I have the drop-down menu for which the source is as below:

```
<select name="issuer">
<option selected="selected" value="15">MBBTampereRootCA
</option><option value="66222">OMS_CA1
</option><option value="66225">OMS_CA2
</option><option value="71463">stefanSpiel
</option></select>
```

and I need to select "stefanSpiel" please tell me how can i do that ??

I tried with Multiple possible options, but not successful.

I have tried these options:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("option.stefanSpiel")
browser.find_element_by_link_text('option.stefanSpiel');
```

and also these:

```
'element = browser.find_element_by_name("issuer")'
'target = select (option, stefanSpiel)'
'action_chains = ActionChains(browser)'
'action_chains.drag_and_drop(element, target)'

'ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(element).click(target).perform()'
```

But all i got is : 
    'selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:'

Thanks,

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: I don't know about python but I have done that in Java, could it help you if I paste it here if you know how to adapt it to python ?

Comment: With a bit more html it might be easier to help you. The containing select element may have an id that could make it quite simple to get it via selenium.

Comment: I have tried these options:

 browser = webdriver.Firefox()
 browser.find_element_by_css_selector("option.stefanSpiel")
 browser.find_element_by_link_text('option.stefanSpiel');
 
and also these:

 'element = browser.find_element_by_name("issuer")'
 'target = select (option, stefanSpiel)'
 'action_chains = ActionChains(browser)'
 'action_chains.drag_and_drop(element, target)'
 
 'ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(element).click(target).perform()'

But all i got is : 
 'selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:'

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is by clicking the 'select' element.
This will 'open' the drop-down and make all the drop-down
options visible to our driver. 
Now we will need to click the desired element.

For example, lets take a look at the following html (it's very similar to the html you provided)
I took it from http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmlselect.php:

```
<select name="selectionField"> 
  <option value="CA">California -- CA </option>
  <option value="CO">Colorado -- CO</option>
  <option value="CN">Connecticut -- CN</option>
</select>
```

For this example I will use xpaths.
Lets say I have the xpath of the 'select' element:

```
xpath = '/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/div[4]/select'
```

I would like to select the option "Connecticut -- CN"

One way to do it is this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver  = webdriver.Firefox()

# navigate to the page that contains the html I provided  
driver.get('http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmlselect.php')

# the xpath of the <select> elemnt
xpath = '/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/div[4]/select'

# click on the <select> element to open the dropdown
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()

# select the desired option
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath+'/*[contains(text(), "Connecticut -- CN")]').click()
```

Comment: XPaths are brittle if you are working with multiple browsers since the XPaths would be different. I've had more success with driver.find_element_by_link_text("YourSelectionHere") when working with options in a select element.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use the `Select()` class as it exists to handle `select` elements.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

select_element = Select(driver.find_element_by_name("issuer"))
select_element.select_by_visible_text("stefanSpiel")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all... Tried as below and it works... not sure to what extent it is good:

```
element = browser.find_element_by_name("issuer")
element.send_keys('stefanSpiel' + Keys.RETURN)
```

Thanks again :)